# Using jquery 'this' to return selected option from dropdown, but it returns all dropdowns on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a page with a list of almost identical select boxes. I want my function to return the selected value just in the box that's been changed; right now it returns the selected value for *all* boxes on the page. I think I am misusing 'this' somehow but can't figure out how.

```
<ul class="edgetoedge" id="finisherlist">
<form method="post">
<li class="entry">
<span class="finishingposition">1</span>
<span class="runnerblock">
<select placeholder="Finisher name" name="finisher" 
    class="finisherchoice" onChange="saveFinishOrder();">
<option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Select runner</option>
<option value="1">Bob</option>
<option value="2">Peter</option>
</select></span>
</li>
<li class="entry">
<span class="finishingposition">2</span>
<span class="runnerblock">
<select placeholder="Finisher name" name="finisher" class="finisherchoice"     
    onChange="saveFinishOrder();">
<option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Select runner</option>
<option value="1">Bob</option>
<option value="2">Peter</option>
</select></span>
</li>
</form>
</ul>
```

And my separate JavaScript looks like this:

```
function saveFinishOrder() {
alert($(this +'option:selected').text());
}
```

When I change one of the dropdowns I get an alert like "PeterSelectRunner" - ie it returns me the current selected values of all dropdowns on the page. What I want is to get the value of just that dropdown, so that I can then save it into a table.

*EDIT* deleted misplaced tags in example code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onChange="saveFinishOrder(this);"
```

and

```
function saveFinishOrder(elem) {
    alert($(elem).val());
}
```

Comment: This partially solves it. It returns the value of the option as specified in the tag. What I'd actually like to do is return the text of that option (my bad; I worded the question poorly). If I change val() to text() I get the text of all possible options; is there something else I can use to return the text of just the selected item?

Comment: For that, use: `alert($(elem).find(':selected').text());`

Comment: Thats because of duplicated closing tags </span> and </select> before the end of options list. Clean your HTML :)

Comment: Yeah, @user689127 should not have `<option>` tags outside of a `<select>`

Comment: Awesome - thanks James, `alert($(elem).find(':selected').text());` works great. Hck: closing tags are in the right place in the real html, that was just my mistake when making it into a simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function saveFinishOrder() {
  alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
}
```

Besides, check your HTML, you have duplicated closing tags  and  before the end of options list.

Comment: This returns a blank alert in Chrome. I'm not sure why. I'm very new to this so happy to run troubleshooting steps if you can tell me what.

Comment: I`ve used function with $('select').change(saveFinishOrder); Another way is to add function argument and use it like described below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098451/using-jquery-this-to-return-selected-option-from-dropdown-but-it-returns-all-d/6098523#6098523